# Android чтение кириллицы из текстового файла(UTF-8)

Tags: java, android, utf-8, кириллица

Пытаюсь прочитать текст из TXT файла. Вот код, который производит чтение:

```
private String readFromTXT(String filePath) {
    StringBuilder textSB = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            textSB.append(line);
            textSB.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not read this file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return textSB.toString();
}
```

Но на экран выводятся � вместо кириллицы. Латиница отображается правильно. Когда я вывожу в TextView обычную строку кириллицы (которая не читается из файла, а просто объявляется в коде), то символы отображаются верно.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно `.txt` сохранён не в `utf-8`

Comment: @zTrap Спасибо, действительно, проблема оказалась в этом. Странно то, что я выбираю в Notepad++ кодировку UTF-8 сохраняю, снова открываю этот файл, а Notepad уже показывает другую кодировку. Попробовал создать файл на самом android, через офис, моя программа его нормально читает, но файлы, которые я с винды перекидываю нет.

Comment: Для Notpad++ необходимо сохранять в формате `utf-8 без BOM`